# Checkbox em DatagridView C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, datatable

Boa tarde. 
Tenho um datagrid view com uma coluna do tipo checkbox, amarrado a um DataTable com a coluna do tipo checkbox também. O meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho que percorrer uma lista de presença, se o aluno estiver presente, tenho que setar o check como true, caso contrário, não faço nada. Como fazer isso?

dt.rows.add(?);

Comment: Você poderia explicar um pouco melhor a sua situação? Esta lista de alunos é a que está no `DataGridView` ou ela virá de outro lugar e você irá comparar com os valores do `DataGridView`? Complemente um pouco mais a sua pergunta que talvez eu possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Este código varre um `gridview` e marca/habilita o estado do `checkbox`
Se baseie nesse exemplo para resolver seu problema :

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
  {
     DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[i];
     dgv.Rows[i].Cells["NomeDaColunaDoCheckBox"].Value = true;
  }
```

Comment: Não resolve o meu problema, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que seja um DataTable de presença do Aluno, 
com a seguinte estrutura:

```
-|Data      |Presenca
1|02/05/2017|true
2|01/05/2017|false
```

você vai percorrer a lista de presença, e se encontrar o aluno, irá adicionar uma linha dessa data. Ex:

```
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r["Data"] = DateTime.Now;
r["Presenca"] = true;

dt.Rows.Add(r);
```

Se a DataTable estiver como DataSource do GridView:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Grid.DataSource;
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r["Data"] = DateTime.Now;
r["Presenca"] = true;

dt.Rows.Add(r);

Grid.DataSource = dt;
```